# My canvas stretches vertically and horizontally, but the image inside does not

Tags: wpf, xaml, vertical-alignment, stretch, alignment

I'm creating a popup menu a ToggleButton and a Popup control. All of which are contained within a canvas. The following image is of the bottom right corner of my application. I set my Canvas so that's in the Index 1 column, stretches 2 columns, and is in the second to bottom row.

[image]

The gray image is just a place holder. From the XAML below, you can see that I've set everything to stretch. The Canvas stretches, but nothing else does. Commenting out the StackPanel and/or the Label does nothing. So I'm convinced neither are the cause. The ToggleButton isn't stretching to the size of the Canvas.

[image]

I did a screenshot so I could highlight those relevant portions, better. But if I need to paste the code, I can.

*EDIT*

Updated XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid Name="ToggleButtonCanvas" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnPluginMenu" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border x:Name="bdr" BorderThickness="0">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="< omitted >" Stretch="Fill" TileMode="None" />
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Label Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Content="Menu" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </StackPanel>
                <Popup Placement="Relative"  HorizontalOffset="-120" VerticalOffset="-130" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnPluginMenu}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btnPluginMenu, Path=IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" PopupAnimation="Scroll">
                    <Grid Background="Gray">
                        <Grid.BitmapEffect>
                            <DropShadowBitmapEffect />
                        </Grid.BitmapEffect>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Canvas does not stretch its child elements. Use a Grid instead.

From the Remarks in the [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) documentation in MSDN:

> Canvas is the only panel element that has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has default Height and Width properties of
>   zero, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes
>   its child elements. **Child elements of a Canvas are never resized**, they
>   are just positioned at their designated coordinates. This provides
>   flexibility for situations in which inherent sizing constraints or
>   alignment are not needed or wanted. For cases in which you want child
>   content to be automatically resized and aligned, it is usually best to
>   use a Grid element.

You can simply replace `Canvas` by `Grid` in your XAML. There is no need to define rows or columns.

Comment: That... sort of worked. It stretches horizontally now, but not vertically. I placed a green border around the Grid so you can better see what's happening during runtime. I'm going to edit my original post to include the updated XAML. http://i2.minus.com/i3N8CGnhcgzy8.png

Comment: @ernest `StackPanels` are only meant to be as tall as their children, and aren't supposed to grow to fill all available space. Use a `DockPanel` or a `Grid` instead of a `StackPanel`, and it should work.

Comment: @Rachel Thanks, Rachel. A DockPanel pretty much fixed everything. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @Clemens I'm going to accept your answer, Clemens. I had to change the Canvas to a grid, but I also had to change the StackPanel to a DockPanel. Thanks a lot for the help.